# how to use two parallel Aggregation for elasticsearch nest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

Like bellow http request: 
base on TERM "service_project" aggr, there are 2 another SUM aggr "service_hour_price" and "servic_part_price". Can I use Elasticsearch Nest do the same thing?

```
      "aggs": {
        "3": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "service_project",
            "size": 50,
            "order": {
              "1": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "1": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "service_hour_price"
              }
            },
            "2": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "servic_part_price"
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

Now I can use only one SUM Aggr base on That Term Aggr, like this:

```
                return s.Aggregations(a => a
                .Terms("names", st => st
                    .Field(o => o.service_project)
                    .OrderDescending("sum")
                    .Size(term_count)
                    .Aggregations(aa => aa
                        .Sum("sum", m => m
                            .Field(o => o.service_hour_price)))));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
s.Aggregations(a => a
    .Terms("3", t => t
        .Field("service_project")
        .Size(50)
        .OrderDescending("1")
        .Aggregations(aa => aa
            .Sum("1", sum => sum.Field("service_hour_price"))
            .Sum("2", sum => sum.Field("service_part_price")))
    ));
```

Hope it helps.